# Old anime movie involving a boy raised by a robot and a ship called 'Siegfried'

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

A boy was raised by a robot guy and I remember there was a ship called 'Siegfried,' I think, and it was powered by the bad sister. I also remember that the robot died protecting the boy, now a teen.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made? Also, who or what did the robot protect the boy from?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: The only works I can think of (and, indeed, a cursory anidb check can find) with a ship called Siegfried are Gundam 0080: War in the Pocket (which fits if you ignore most of the details in this question and skew your interpretation of this question to "coming of age tragedy where the main female character turns out to be an enemy") and Macross Delta (which fits if, uh...I got nothing). Neither of which are movies. More details would be greatly appreciated to fully narrow this down.